# NVM not changing Node version on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, version, nvm

I have successfully used NVM to install different versions of node. And in the past I've been able to run commands like `nvm use __` or `nvm alias default ___`, and then run `node -v` to see a successful version change. But now I can't seem to change my version of node. I suspect it's a path issue?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will be good if you can provide more details like what versions you have installed and how did you aliased.

If you have the proper aliasing you can easily switch between versions using the following command,

```
nvm use <alias_name>
```

And you can alias using below command,

```
nvm alias default 6.11.5
```

For more details check the documentation: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm